# What is the error Error: [LWC error]: The `insertBefore` method is available only on elements that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I create a Lightning Web Component with a lightning-card and a lightning-record-edit-form and added it to a Lightning Community page. In debug mode I get a console log error message for pretty much every field.

The message is:

> Error: [LWC error]: The `insertBefore` method is available only on elements that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive

The component is completely functional, however I don't like seeing those messages and not know what they mean.

Screenshot snippet of the message:
[image]

Comment: check this:- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252266/appendchild-to-non-empty-div-in-lightning-web-component

Comment: @sanketkumar, I'm not using the directive lwc:dom="manual"

Comment: You need to add the attribute `lwc:dom="manual"` to the part of the code that you are going to `manually` manipulate. You should consider an `aura:if` or something else to avoid this

Comment: @CasparHarmer, this is not an aura component. This is a lightning component. Also, I'm not manually manipulating the DOM.

Comment: I meant to write `if:true|false={expression}` - a html directive. Anyway since you are using a built in component, then the salesforce team that made the component needs to add `lwc::dom="manual"` to their component.