# LWC not formatting the string in HTML tags

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I am fetching below string from apex and I assign it to track property in jS and in HTML I add that track property inside div tag and instead of rendering it in formatted text it render as shown in below image.

HTML:

```
<div>
    {stringFromApex}
<div>
```

String coming from apex

```
   <h2>Collection</h2><ol><li>0309Cab Calculated</li><li>01A2</li><li>00005</li><li>1 ALQ</li><li>000 New OU Analyte</li><li>% Viability (CPT)</li><li>% Cryocrit</li></ol>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [appendChild to non empty div in lightning web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252266/appendchild-to-non-empty-div-in-lightning-web-component)

Comment: Thank you Rahul for the link, but my problem solved by Pranay's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the string from apex is html markup, more likely from Rich Text Area. You can use [lightning-formatted-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) to maintain formatting.

```
<div>
 <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={stringFromApex}>
    </lightning-formatted-rich-text>        
<div>
```

[image]