# LWC Error: appendChild is not a function / Cannot add property innerHTML, object is not extensible

Tags: apex, trigger, api, performance

I am trying to add an `iframe` element to a container div:

```
<template>
    <div class="container" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import PP from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/penpal'

initialised = false;
iframe;
container;

async renderedCallback() {

    if (this.initialised) {
        return;
    }

    this.initialised = true;

    // load Penpal
    await loadScript(this, PP).catch(error => console.error(error));

    // get container
    this.container = this.template.querySelector('div.container');

    // create iframe
    this.iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    this.iframe.src = 'https://x.visualforce.com/apex/page';

    // HERE: I try and add the iframe to the DOM

    // bind the iframe to Penpal
    const connection = Penpal.connectToChild({
        // The iframe to which a connection should be made
        iframe: this.iframe
    });
}
```

Using the `appendChild` method:

```
this.container.appendChild(this.iframe);
```

I get this error:

> appendChild is not a function

Using the `innerHTML` approach:

```
this.container.innerHTML = this.iframe.outerHTML;
```

I get this error:

> Cannot add property innerHTML, object is not extensible

I also tried adding a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener:

```
connectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        this.container.appendChild(this.iframe);
    }.bind(this), false);
}
```

But the `DOMContentLoaded` event never fires?

**Question**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I get the iframe added to the DOM successfully?

Comment: It there a specific reason you don't have the iframe explicitly part of the template with conditional rendering around it and using tracked properties to handle its attribute values?

Comment: @PhilW - thanks for the quick response. I've added a little more code to my example to give more context. When I include the `iframe` in the template code like this `<iframe src="https://x.visualforce.com/apex/page"></iframe>`, I get an error from `Penpal` saying the `iframe` does not have a `src` set... and `Penpal` [documentation](https://github.com/Aaronius/penpal) dynamically adds the `iframe` ... but I am open any suggestions :-)

Comment: OK I think I understand... you're going through the hoops to allow use of a third-party package within your LWC, hence the use of ```lwc:dom="manual"``` as per the [docs](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript_third_party_library)... perhaps you need to push the JS into a static resource rather than embedded within the LWC component itself to avoid the LWC compiler from doing stuff to it?

Comment: @PhilW - I have already loaded the JS lib as a static resource, which is being used in both the LWC and Visualforce page. Code example above extended further.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the extra bits where you create the iframe itself, outside the "penpal" library but also so it is outside the LWC component source file... it is probably unnecessary but I do know that the LWC compiler does change it component code rather significantly...