# In LWC if we can dynamically add script and append it to header?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforce-id

There is one use case of mine where I needed to dynamically append js to header.
Is there any way we can append script tag with some js in lightning web component.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. The framework will prevent your code from running. You must use [loadScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader) in order to load scripts. Since the JavaScript is under your control, you can choose which of several scripts you'd like to add, but this must still be statically bound in a Static Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create an empty div and add this attribute-> lwc:dom="manual"
you can then access the div from javascript using the Id/Class name and append the script.

The link below has a perfect example of how to achieve this:

[appendChild to non empty div in lightning web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252266/appendchild-to-non-empty-div-in-lightning-web-component)